# Can I use one getter method for several classes?

Tags: java

Is it possible to use the `getError()` method in the `GreenhouseControls` class to grab the `errorcode` of either `WindowMalfunction` or `PowerOut` or do I have to include the method in each inner class?

```
public class GreenhouseControls {

    public int errorcode;

    public class WindowMalfunction extends Event {
        int errorcode = 1; 
    }

    public class PowerOut extends Event { 
        int errorcode = 2;
    }

    getError(){ return errorcode }
}
```

Comment: Currently WindowMalfunction and PowerOut are *not* subclasses of GreenhouseControls.  Should they be for the purpose of this question?  It makes a difference.

Comment: No they shouldn't be subclasses. I meant inner classes.

Comment: I think you didn't grab the concepts of classes, fields and methods yet. So it's much too soon to start using inner classes. I would start by learning those concepts first, with only top-level classes.

Comment: Yes, you can use `int GetError()` just because it returns variable of the same class.

Comment: @PM77-1: you're saying nonsense.

Comment: What exactly do you want anyway?

Comment: @JBNizet I do not think so. `errorcode` in inner classes simply shadow `errorcode` from the outer class. So OP has a regular getter for the outer class.

Comment: I want to be able to use the getError() method provided in GreenhouseControls to access the errorcode of either one of the inner classes provided. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @LooMeenin: How would it know which one you wanted?

Comment: Yes, you can. Inner classes have access to outer class variables. Get rid of `int` in inner classes.  This way your inner classes will be able to update the same outer class variable and your getError() will return this value.  Another question is: why would you want to do it this way?

Comment: The question doesn't even make sense. You need an *instance* of those classes to have access to their errorCode field.

Comment: I'm not sure! Just started programming. I guess I can't do it. It's for a Java class I'm taking and the assignment said to provide a getError() method in the GreenhouseControls class to access the errorcodes in the inner classes.

Comment: You provided to few details to get a good advice. The code above doesn't even compile, and doesn't make sense. We don't know what you're trying to achieve, what those classes are for, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce an intermediate superclass to your events that defines the `getError` method once:

```
public class ErrorEvent extends Event {
    private final int errorCode;

    protected ErrorEvent(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public int getError() {
        return errorCode;
    } 
}

public class WindowMalfunction extends ErrorEvent {
    public WindowMalfunction() { super(1); }
}

public class PowerOut extends ErrorEvent { 
    public PowerOut() { super(2); }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was about to write.